# How can I attach a static external IP address with a GCP Cloud TPU VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-tpu

I want to use a static reserved IP address with a Cloud TPU VM.

For a regular (non-TPU) Compute Engine instance, I can just use the web interface and go to the "External IP addresses" tab of the "VPC Network" page, select an existing external IP (or create a new one), and choose to attach it to a Compute Engine instance from the dropdown. However, my TPU VM does not show up in this same dropdown.

Is it possible to reserve and attach a static external IP address to my TPU VM by some other means?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's what I see in the GCP web interface when I select the TPU VM:
[image]

Comment: Hi Daniel! How did you deploy the TPU VM? You see, as explained by [Internal IP address ranges for TPU nodes](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/internal-ip-blocks) `Each TPU node runs on a peer VPC network that Google manages` so TPU nodes can not have a public IP. What’s odd is that when I followed Google's [Creating a Cloud TPU](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/creating-deleting-tpus#creating_a_cloud_tpu) I got a VM attached to the TPU node and I was able to reserve the external IP as usual. Can you attach more information about your case? Like screenshots or error logs?

Comment: Hi Armando! I deployed the TPU VM via these instructions: https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/users-guide-tpu-vm
I guess it's a "preview" feature where you geta TPU VM that you can actually SSH into, but which isn't the same as a regular Compute Engine VM with a TPU node attached. That's my understanding at least. Does that make sense?
GCP is giving my TPU VM an ephemeral public IP address, but not a static one.

Comment: @ArmandoCuevas I added a screenshot to my main post, let me know if there's anything else that would be helpful. I can't think of any particular error logs to attach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you currently can't assign a static IP to a TPU VM yet like you can a GCE node (e.g. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address).

This may be supported in the future though!

Comment: Awww okay. Thank you! For now I guess I will set up a separate VM with a static IP on the same VPC network and use that to proxy requests.